Python opencv draws polygons outside of lines
[edited] It appears there is a new bug in opencv that introduces an issue causing fillPoly's boundaries to exceed polylines's.
Here is humble code to draw a red filled polygon with a blue outline.
import cv2
import numpy as np

def draw_polygon(points, resolution=50):
    
    # create a blank black canvas
    img = np.zeros((resolution, resolution, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    pts = np.array(points, np.int32)
    pts = pts.reshape((-1, 1, 2))
    
    # draw a filled polygon in blue
    cv2.fillPoly(img, [pts], (0, 0, 255))
    
    # draw an outline in red
    cv2.polylines(img, [pts], True, (255, 0, 0), 1)
    
    # show the image
    cv2.imshow("Polygon", img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    
    
# why is the infill outside the line?
if __name__ == "__main__":

    # 4 vertices of the quad (clockwise)
    quad = np.array([[[44, 27],
                      [7, 37],
                      [7, 19],
                      [38, 19]]])
    
    draw_polygon(quad)

QUESTION
The polygon's infill appears to bleed outside of the outline (two highlighted pixels). I'm looking for a temporary solution until this bug is addressed so the infill stays completely inside the outline.
Solution has to work with concave polygons.


I don't see this on Ubuntu.  What's your operating system?  There is always confusion in polygon coordinates over whether the right and bottom edges are PART of the polygon or just outside of it.

Using a line thickness of 2 (last parameter to polylines()) seems to entirely cover up the polygon border.  Adding a parameter to polylines() with a value of cv2.LINE_AA also seems to help, but may not be the look you're going for (and perhaps might not work in every case).

Can reproduce on Windows with OpenCV 4.8/4.9/4.10, but not with 4.7 or anything older. So it looks like a relatively recent issue.

It seems to me like it originated with this bugfix: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/23076

I added a note to that pull request and a link back to this question, but it may be worth filing a separate bug report.

opencv drawing really should be switched to using OpenGL or whatever. NIHing graphics caused this issue. if need be, someone can shim a cpu renderer under that but it must conform to OpenGL's behavior.

@ChristophRackwitz Yeah, although probably not OpenGL -- for good looking 2D graphics, that's opening yet another giant can of worms (From what I've read and tried, the line and point drawing primitives are generally ugly, limited and inconsistent).

they certainly are in OpenCV. I'd welcome anything to replace that mess. a library called AGG might be an alternative. I think OpenCV shouldn't limit itself to 2D graphics, shouldn't leave 3D graphics to be attempted inconsistently, wildly, with heavy third party dependencies (cvv, ovis, viz). It should bring 2D and 3D in all cases. in 5.x there's a new triangleRasterize but I'll wait and see if that's any good and where its limitations are (also for 5.x to be released).

@ChristophRackwitz Yeah, AGG would be a nice option.

Where there's a will there's a way. fillPoly appears to be able to draw as a line when given only two vertices. And that line matches the edges of the previously drawn polygon.   \o/
I modified my code to draw the edges as a single fillPoly call and it seems to work decently.
I would still prefer if fillPoly and polyLines would match, but for now I am unblocked.
import cv2
import numpy as np

def draw_polygon(points, resolution=50):
    
    # create a blank black canvas
    img = np.zeros((resolution, resolution, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    poly_pts = np.array(points, np.int32)
    edge_pts = np.vstack([poly_pts, poly_pts[0]])
    
    # draw a filled polygon in blue
    cv2.fillPoly(img, [poly_pts], (0, 0, 255))
    
    # draw the outlines as individual edges,
    # drawn in a single fillPoly call, in red
    e0 = edge_pts[:-1]
    e1 = edge_pts[1:]
    edge_polygons = np.hstack((e0[:,None], e1[:,None]))
    cv2.fillPoly(img, edge_polygons, (255, 0, 0))  
    
    # show the image
    cv2.imshow("Polygon", img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    
    
# better outline
if __name__ == "__main__":

    # 4 vertices of the quad (clockwise)
    quad = np.array([[44, 27],
                      [7, 37],
                      [7, 19],
                      [38, 19]])
    
    draw_polygon(quad)




"I would still prefer" -- did ya file the bug? ;) This definitely shouldn't be happening, and it didn't until relatively recently. That line as drawn by fillPoly looks wrong -- those bits where the red spilled out ought to be black IMHO.

i agree 100% about the fillPoly issue still being present. the most important part for my application was to keep the color contained which this satisfies until the bug is resolved. i'll file a bug if no one else has already

Yep, please do so, you seem to be in the best position to do that having discovered the problem. I just added a comment to what seems to be where this originates, but I'd think a separate bug report would be useful to have.

@DanMašek https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/26130

This was trickier than I thought.
The only solution I could come up with is to use floodfill.  It works, but I'm not sure about my seed point calculation.
x = sum([p[0] for p in points[0]]) // len(points[0])
y = sum([p[1] for p in points[0]]) // len(points[0])
seed = (x,y)
cv2.floodFill(img, None, seed, (0, 0, 255))

Original example Updated with floodfill
import cv2
import numpy as np

def draw_polygon(points, resolution=50):

    # create a blank black canvas
    img = np.zeros((resolution, resolution, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    pts = np.array(points, np.int32)
    pts = pts.reshape((-1, 1, 2))

    # draw an outline in red
    cv2.polylines(img, [pts], True, (255, 0, 0), 1)

    # Need an inside point to start flooding from.
    # !! Not sure if this method is guaranteed to be inside the polygon !!
    x = sum([p[0] for p in points[0]]) // len(points[0])
    y = sum([p[1] for p in points[0]]) // len(points[0])
    inside_point = (x, y)

    # floodfill the polygon with blue
    cv2.floodFill(img, None, inside_point, (0, 0, 255))

    # show the image
    cv2.imshow("Polygon", img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()



# why is the infill outside the line?
if __name__ == "__main__":

    # 4 vertices of the quad (clockwise)
    quad = np.array([[[44, 27],
                      [7, 37],
                      [7, 19],
                      [38, 19]]])

    draw_polygon(quad)


good solution but unfortunately i need to handle concave qads and it's possible the coordinates obtained by averaging a the points would land outside and fill the wrong area.

i think the only way to go is to use fillPoly to draw every edge... a bit hacky but will probably work... i just did a test and to my great surprise if you feed fillPoly just two points, it will draw a line exactly where it needs to be.... so i'm hopeful :)

Using fillPoly to also draw the lines, Cleaver!
